# Nested Listview in Xamarin.Android - Trying with Listview inside Listview

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to show a ListView inside a ListView

This is to build a nested ListView in **Xamarin.Android** (Not Xamarin.Form), but the second ListView just show one Item.

I created an other layout to put one Label Text and the ListView, using the basedapater to fill the Main LV.

```
        View listitem = convertView;
        listitem = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListViewDesign, parent, false);

        TextView TxtNo = listitem.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TxtNo);
        LinearLayout layout = listitem.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
        layout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


        ListView ListLibros = listitem.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListLibros);
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();
        TxtNo.Text = mItem[position].AUTOR;

        for (var i = 0; i < mItem[position].LIBROS.Count(); i++) {

            lista.Add(mItem[position].LIBROS[i].Descripcion);

        }



        ListLibros.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(ListLibros.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, lista);

        return listitem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two methods to achieve it.

**1.custom a ListView** ,override `OnMeaSure` method like this:

```
class MyListView :ListView
{
    protected MyListView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public MyListView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(Integer.MaxValue >> 2,
            MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

then use the MyListView as the inner ListView.

**2.don't use ListView inner,use a LinearLayout filled by Views**,like this:

```
LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) listitem.findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
list.removeAllViews();
for (var i = 0; i < mItem[position].LIBROS.Count(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context); // you could custon View here
        textView.Text = mItem[position].LIBROS[i].Descripcion;
        lista.Add(textView );

    }
```